# Не правильно отчисление в запросе sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 (TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, user_todo_send.time, NOW()) + user_todo_send.unit_time) as seconds
```

эта часть запроса в которой я для вычисления сколько времени осталось суммирую разницу между текущим временем и TIMESTAMP записи потом к этой разнице добавляю время в секундах, но в итоге число округляется и приходит неправильным

Comment: Приведите примеры (какие исходные значения, что ожидаете получить и что получаете)

Comment: А что вы хотиет получить, если сказать человеческим языком? time это видимо время какого-то события, а что такое unit_time?

Comment: time это TIMESTAMP (2015-06-09 12:00:00) события а unit_time - в секундах время например (1 час или 3600 сек.)

Comment: Мне нужно получить сколько осталось времени до окончания события в принципе я руководствуюсь формулой  ((время создания + час) -  текущее время)

Comment: Примеров не будет?

Comment: Где примеры? Где кусок кода, а то по Вашим переменным не всё ясно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1, t2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) дает разницу в секундах между t1 и t2. Если время t2 позже чем t1, то эта разница положительная.

Выражение для проверки:

```
SET @t1 = TIMESTAMP('2015-06-09 11:14:00');
SET @t2 = TIMESTAMP('2015-06-09 11:15:00');
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @t1, @t2) + 200;
```

Результат 260.
Вы последним аргументом поставили NOW(), это выражение означает "сколько времени прошло с момента t1" и эта цифра будет постоянно расти с каждым вызовом! А по задумке должна уменьшаться.

Поменяйте now() и time местами, убедитесь, что в полях именно те значения, которые вы ждете (time - время начала и unit_time - продолжительность как целое число секунд) и наслаждайтесь!

Comment: ну я это понял и в ответе указал кстати, спасибо за объяснение ))

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос отпал, решил проблему таким запросом в помощь пришла функция DATE_ADD

```
 SELECT (TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, NOW(), DATE_ADD(user_todo_send.time, INTERVAL user_todo_send.unit_time SECOND))) as seconds
```

Comment: Проблема была в неправильном порядке аргументов. DATE_ADD не при чем! :)

Comment: Да это тоже факт, но я побывал менять порядок аргументов и добавлять через +  время в сек  и неправильно считало, а с помощью  DATE_ADD получилось

Comment: Значит плохо проб**о**вал. Ну получилось и хорошо! Просто желательно вникать в причину и следствие, а не копировать бездумно. :)